# “No cells were found.” Error in Excel 2016 when running VBA script

Tags: vba, excel

I’m pretty new to VBA scripting, and I have the following problem.

At work, I have to go through huge Excel sheets containing hyperlinks to external audio files. The hyperlinks are all in the following format:

```
=HYPERLINK("path_to_file_including_file_name", "file_name")
```

I’m very tired of clicking the hyperlinks with my mouse, and there is no way to open them with a hotkey, so I decided to create a small macro to solve my problem. The macro is stored in my personal macro workbook (because I want to use it with all of my Excel sheets):

```
Sub ClickHyperlink()
'
' ClickHyperlink Macro
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+O
' 
params = Split(ActiveCell.Formula, Chr(34))
ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=params(1)
End Sub
```

When I open an Excel sheet, this VBA macro works until I edit the file and save it. After this, it shows the following error message: “No cells were found.” If I close the file and open it again, the macro works again until I edit the file and save it.

It really doesn’t make any sense to me. What am I doing wrong?

I would be very grateful for any help.

**Update**. Added the screenshot of the error message and of the IDE.

[image]

I also noticed something quite strange: even when the script stops working when called from the Excel file I’m working on, it still works perfectly if run from the IDE.

Comment: No idea what's going on here (please indicate which line raises the error) but why are you `Split`ting the formula instead of traversing the workbook's `Hyperlinks` collection?

Comment: Thanks David, at first I tried to use ActiveCell.Hyperlinks, but in my case it doesn’t seem to work with hyperlinks created with =HYPERLINK(). However, it works if the cell simply contains a web URL

Comment: OK, yes I see that now. I'd also be curious to know whether there are any worksheet or workbook-level event procedures in the files you're opening. And which line is raising the error?

Comment: Because that error message is usually (always?) associated with the `SpecialCells` method of range object, and you're not using that anywhere in the code provided, so the error would seem to be raising in some other procedure.

Comment: David, thanks for your help. I tried to find out which line is raising the error by employing the following syntax: `On Error Go To` and `Debug.Print Erl` (I numbered all the lines in the script), however it only outputs zeros. Also, interestingly, when I trace the script using F8, it works perfectly every time.

Comment: And I just checked, there are no macros in the files I am opening.

Comment: `print Erl` isn't necessary. when the error raises just enter debug mode and see what line is highlighted in the IDE.

Comment: I just tried it again. When I get the error message and switch to IDE, there are no highlighted lines, which probably means that the error happens outside of the script.

Comment: can you screenshot the error and IDE window

Comment: Thanks David, I will do this when I’m back in the office tomorrow

Comment: I added the screenshot to the post. Thanks!

Comment: that's not a standard error dialog, and I'm 1000% certain that your code isn't causing it. I'm guessing that's a simple message box that's being displayed from an add-in or COM add-in or another procedure. check the workbook and worksheet modules for code.

Comment: Thanks for your help David, but the workbook and worksheet modules contain no code.

Comment: you've got at least one other book besides your personal.xlsb, what's in there? do you have any 3rd party COM add-ins installed? And can you reproduce this problem in a new/empty workbook and/or on another computer?

Comment: The other file I have open is a glossary (a simple 2-column list of terms and their descriptions organized in 4 sheets depending on the language). I tried to create a new file and copy several hyperlinks to it and it seems to work perfectly all the time. My conclusion is that the problem is indeed related to the files I work with (they’re not created in Excel, but generated by Perforce Helix which a DAM/version control system we use internally)

Comment: Are they Excel files created from the other application? Or are they more generic e.g., CSV or TXT files?

Comment: They are Excel (xlsx) files.

Comment: XLSX files can't contain VBA, so they aren't the problem. Unfortunately this is not an answerable question here on SO. The code doesn't raise an error in other workbooks (point of fact: it's actually not raising an error in *this* particular instance either) and it's not even clear that your code has anything to do with the appearance of this warning/message box). Others can't reproduce the problem. Cumulatively this suggests the problem source is *not* this code, but something else specific to your environment. I still suspect there's an Add-in to do something behind the scenes...

Comment: David, thank you very much for your time and willingness to help. I came to the same conclusion, unfortunately, I will have to live with this problem for the time being.

Comment: Cheers. One last thought: your final observation (*I also noticed something quite strange...*) further supports the theory that there's something else happening in your environment, *and* that your code (probably) isn't triggering the warning message. I know this isn't the answer you were hoping for :) and hopefully next time you have a question, someone here will be able to answer it!

Comment: Running into this same issue, with the same message box/error message displaying.  My macro is a simple one that counts all the sheets in a workbook, and counts the Visible/Hidden/Very Hidden sheets then displays the number of each in a Message Box.  Other macros I have work fine, and this one worked until recently, and still works if run from the VBE, or from the View Macros window, just not from my keyboard shortcut. It's so frustrating, if anyone has learned anything new in on this in the past four years, please share. Thank you!

Comment: @Sean Hi Sean, since then I discovered that the problem was caused by alternative keyboard layouts, e.g. the hotkeys were working perfectly when the keyboard layout was set to US-EN, but refused to work when it was UK-UA